# Does the Smart Lock for Passwords API allow for silent password changes?

Tags: google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

Is it possible for an app or a web page to change a password stored in smart lock without user interaction? In other words, must a user press a button in order for a password to be changed in smart lock?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the save API and the user has an existing credential with a matching identifier, you can update the password or account type field without showing the user any UI (but they had to see UI and accept to save the info with their Google Account the first time in order to have an existing credential stored)